# Drawing overlay on screen in C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, overlay

Is there any way to draw an invisible overlay on top of the screen (meaning in front of all windows and everything else) in C++ and/or Java?
It doesn't need to support 3D graphics or anything fancy, I just need to be able to draw 
lines/pixels on it.

There are some other solutions that I found on the internet, but they all either

1) don't allow mouse clicks to go through them (onto the windows or other stuff under it) or

2) are only for Windows (I need something that works on Windows and Linux, but Mac support would also be nice).

Comment: What about creating a transparent window, and blocking it at the top of the z-order stack?

Comment: I think that would work. If it was the same size as the display resolution, it would take the entire screen, and the mouse would click through it. Can you make that an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way could be create a transparent window which fits on the entire screen size, and lock it at the top of the z-order stack.
Thats what I usually do when write screensavers.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? A transparent window will consume all clicks so the computer becomes unusable, not a problem for screensavers, but a problem for most other applications.